# Spring MongoDB JAVA Sorting Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, mongodb-query, microservices

I have tried with the below code to short id(string) parameter but it is not sorting correctly.

```
// Apply sorting 
   if (sort != null) {
   query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, sort));
```

**OR**

```
// Apply sorting
if (sort != null) {
    Sort sortOptions = Sort.by(Sort.Order.desc(sort)); // Sort in descending order
    query.with(sortOptions);
}
```

**OUTPUT** :

Suppose IDs are 5, 10, and 11.
It gives 5 -> 11 -> 10 but it should be 11, 10, 5.

Comment: First of all are you sure that sort is not null. Also I am pretty sure that it is simple sorting you can find in stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, very obvious. It's not null. That's why I am getting 5 -> 11 -> 10.
And actually I checked, but same results

Comment: Can you send structure of document that you are using? Maybe Id is not in first layer of json

Comment: {
  "_id": "5",
 “managementId”: "238764827364827t367",
 "source": {
      "refValue": "http://cvVYqgTCOAfKG.hldhdbTbO2djQIWelGBb",
    “type": “reference",
    “baseType": "netstats"
  },
 “type”: “netstatic”
}

Answer (score 1):

It's correct because your `id` is `String` which `'10' < '5'`. To solve this issue we have 2 options:

1. Change your `id` type from `String` to `Long` or `Integer` in your document class.

```
{ 
    "_id": 5 <- this is a number not string
    // other fields
}
```

2. Create another field with `Long` or `Integer` in your document class for sorting. Automatic fill up this column with numeric type by your `id`. Example: setter for new column `Integer.parseInt(getId())`, and sort method will be `Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "numericFieldName")`

```
{ 
    "_id": "5",
    "numericFieldName": 5 <- this is a number
    // other fields
}
```

Comment: But it allowed sort as a sting only in 

query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, sort));

Comment: @Agrawal One option that you can consider is to create another field with Long or Integer for sorting. Example Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "numbericFieldName")

Comment: But the second parameter should be in string only

Comment: Yeah, it's field name. I mean the type of field, your id has type is string so it cannot sort as numeric. Lets update your document structure. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Agrawal is it help?

Comment: Suppose I have id = string, then If I do long a = Integer.parseInt(id), then Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "numbericFieldName"), I again need to put this in string (String.valueOf(a)), is that way you are saying?

Comment: No @Agrawal , I'm talking about document structure, until you have `{ "_id": "5", “numbericFieldName": 5 }` then you can sort on it. Pls check my updated comment